# How to find index of last occurrence of a substring using sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to find last occurrence of space in path which is stored in _data column. But I couldn't find any lastof(X,Y) function or even reverse(X).

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such built-in SQL function, and the Android database API does not allow creating user-defined SQL functions; you have to search for the space in your Java code.